# Find the matrix representing a linear operator $T:\mathbb{R}_3[X]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_2[X] $

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on some practice questions for an upcoming quiz, and I think I have done this question correctly, but I just wanted to clear up a few concepts, that I don't have a great understanding of. Here is the question:

> Let $\mathbb{R}_2[X]$ and $\mathbb{R}_2[X] $ be the space of
>   polynomials of degrees less than or equal to 2 and 3 respectively,
>   with coefficients in  $\mathbb{R} $, with the standard bases
>   $(1,X,X^2)$ and $(1,X,X^2,X^3)$ respectively.
>
> Define the linear operator
>   $T:\mathbb{R}_3[X]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_2[X] $ by:
>
> $$T(g):= g'-\frac{1}{2}(X-2)g''$$
>
> (i) Find the matrix representing $T$ with respect to the standard
>   bases of $\mathbb{R}_2[X] $ and $\mathbb{R}_3[X] $ respectively.
>   (ii) Find a basis for the kernel of T

For (i), I compute T for each component of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}_3[X] $, so I get:

$T(1) = 0 - \frac{1}{2}(X-2)(0) = 0$

$T(X) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}(X-2)(0) = 1$

$T(X^2) = 2X - \frac{1}{2}(X-2)(2) = X+2$

$T(X^3) = 3X^2 - \frac{1}{2}(X-2)(6X) = 6X$

So in matrix form I have:

$
  T=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   0 & 1 & 2 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 6\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

I think this is correct, except I am not too sure what the question means by with respect to both the standard bases? I don't have a good intuitive understanding of this, as so far, I've only done this for transformations between spaces of the same dimension.

For part (ii), I row reduce the above matrix to RREF, and then solve for $c_1, c_2, c_3,
c_4 $,

which gives me a basis of the kernel of:

$t$$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   0\\
   12\\
   -6\\
   1\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ with $t \in \mathbb{R} $

However, when I put the matrix into wolfram alpha to check, it gives this vector as well as $(1,0,0,0)$ as the basis? What could I have done wrong?

I do know that by the rank nullity theorem, since the dimension of $\mathbb{R}_3[X] $ is $4$ $dim(imT) + dim(kerT)$ should be 4. My understanding of image is that in matrix form, it is essentially the columns of the original matrix with leading $1$s in the RREF (which in this case dim(imT) would be $2$?) So I am missing something, which I assume is the extra component of the basis of the kernel? But I am still unsure, how to get $(1,0,0,0)$?

Many thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Your operator goes from a 4-dimensional space to a 3-dimensional, hence, the matrix should be 3 rows, not 4. The standard bases are pretty much what you think they are, $\{1,X,X^2,X^3\}$ and $\{1,X,X^2\}$. Also, just looking at your $T$, it's immediate that $(1,0,0,0)$ is in its nullspace.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the basis of $\mathbb{R}_2[X]$ is $\alpha$ and the basis of $\mathbb{R}_3[X]$ is $\beta$. The matrix representation of $T$ with respect to these bases is \begin{equation} \text{Mtx}_{\alpha,\beta}=\begin{bmatrix}[T(1)]_\alpha,[T(X)]_\alpha,[T(X^2)]_\alpha,[T(X^3)]_\alpha\end{bmatrix}\end{equation} I write $\alpha$ first because it represents the rows of the matrix representation of $T$. Now remember that $\alpha$ contains only three vectors, so any vector in $\alpha$ coordinates will only have three components.

Now as an example take $T(X^2) = X+2$, to write it out explicitly in terms of the alpha basis, we have $T(X^2) = 2\cdot 1+1\cdot X+0\cdot X^2$, so that we have \begin{equation} [T(X^2)]_\alpha=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}. \end{equation} So you calculated $T(\beta_i)$ correctly for each $i$ but you added an extra row. In effect your matrix is a representation for a transformation from $\mathbb{R}_3[X]$ to $\mathbb{R}_3[X]$ in terms of the $\beta$ basis. So we should actually have: \begin{equation} \text{Mtx}_{\alpha,\beta}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&2&0\\0&0&1&6\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.\end{equation} So that is for part (i).

For part (ii), solve the homogenous system associated with the matrix we have calculated. There no need really to even row reduce. It is clear that $x_1$ is a free parameter, since its coefficient is zero in every row. And then taking $x_4$ as a free parameter, we must have $x_3=-6x_4$ and $x_2=-2x_3=-2(-6x_4)=12x_4$. So a general solution is \begin{equation}x_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+x_4\begin{bmatrix}0\\12\\-6\\1\end{bmatrix}, \end{equation} and therefore we have a basis for the kernel: $\{(1,0,0,0)^T,(0,12,-6,1)^T\}$